# Bash function named with the question mark char does not work anymore

Tags: 13.04, bash, command-line, scripts

In Ubuntu 11.10 I had a bash command/alias/function like:

```
function ?() {
  xxx $1
}
```

This worked like a charm.

Now in Ubuntu 13.04 it doesn't work anymore. When I try to execute the command with some argument I get:

> 0: command not found

What has changed that I cannot use this abbreviation anymore?

<sub>P.S. Of course it's possible to change the alias name, it's just a question out of curiousity.</sub>

Comment: I use 13.04 and for me works great in all situations: `function ?`() { xxx $1 }`, `function ? () { xxx $1 }` or `? () { xxx $1 }`. GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release. What is your version?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I tried all the combinations you mentioned and I got the exact same version as you. Still the same error

Comment: Are you sure that you use `bash` shell? If you use this function in a script, first line in the script is: `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu This function is inside my `~/.bash_aliases` and I am using the `gnome-terminal` with this bash.

Comment: I just tested inside `~/.bash_aliases`. Still no problem

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the command(s) that you use inside the function. What command(s) do you use there?

Comment: I just re-saved my `.bash-aliases` as new file and restarted my PC. Strangely now it works like it should. I don't know what caused that, but anyway thank you very much for taking time @Radu :)!

Comment: Well, you should add this last comment as an answer, as long it solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?` is a glob (pattern, wildcard) that'll match filenames consisting of exactly one character; it gets replaced by matching files in the current directory. If there are no matching files in the current directory, `?` will remain unchanged, and your function will be triggered. This is called Pathname Expansion in `man bash` and [Filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion) in the bash reference manual

In this case, you apparently have a file named `0` in the current directory, so `? foo` gets changed to `0 foo` by pathaname expansion, then it tries to run a command named `0` with `foo` as argument. If you remove/rename that file to something longer than one character, your function should start working. Alternatively you can use `\?` or `"?"` or `'?'` instead, to avoid it being treated as a glob.

On a side note, using `?` in a function name is undocumented and not recommended. Only [alphanumerics and underscore](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-name) are documented to work (same as what's allowed for variable names).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the detailed explanation! You were right, for some reason there was a file named `0`. I guess I'll just stick with an alphanumeric character.